# Why my text gets cut off in stripe card element input field on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, stripe-payments

I have my card number input, and whenever it gets focused on mobile, the top of the text just gets cut off, I have pretty much no idea why it happens
Here you can see the code of actual input components, which I imported from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
It works completely fine on desktop but gets completely messed up on mobile, and I have no ideas why. Other inputs don't seem to have this problem

```
  <form style={{ width: "100%" }}>
    <CardNumberElement

      className={styles['card-input']}
      options={{
        placeholder: 'Card number',
        iconStyle: 'default',
        style: {
          base: {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontSize: '16px',
            lineHeight: '20px',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: '#9D9D9D',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#9D9D9D',
            },
            ':-webkit-autofill': {
              fontWeight: '300',
              fontSize: '16px',
              color: '#9D9D9D',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              lineHeight: '20px',
            },
          },
          invalid: {
            color: '#9e2146',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  <div className={styles["secondary-card-info"]}>
    <CardExpiryElement
      className={styles['secondary-card-input']}
      options={{
        style: {
          base: {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontSize: '16px',
            lineHeight: '20px',
            color: '#9D9D9D',
            ':-webkit-autofill': {
              fontWeight: '300',
              fontSize: '16px',
              color: '#9D9D9D',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              lineHeight: '20px',
            },
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#9D9D9D',
            },
          },
          invalid: {
            color: '#9e2146',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
    <CardCvcElement
      className={styles['secondary-card-input']}
      options={{
        style: {
          base: {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontSize: '16px',
            lineHeight: '20px',
            color: '#9D9D9D',
            ':-webkit-autofill': {
              fontWeight: '300',
              fontSize: '16px',
              color: '#9D9D9D',
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              lineHeight: '20px',
            },
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#9D9D9D',
            },
          },
          invalid: {
            color: '#9e2146',
          },
        },
      }}
    />
    </div>
  </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2biI.jpg)

Comment: Without any code or context, it's impossible for everyone to help you.

Comment: 1179 is the hidden numberrrr ahaha

Comment: I advise you to remove the image and re-edit it

Comment: There is basically no private information, so I don't know what to hide there, anyway, ty for your responses

Comment: @johannchopin I don't know what code to put here, as there is basically no code that somehow may mess things with text. Also, I must add that the issue appears only on mobile

Comment: @DanilMednikov You could start with the code of the input itself ;)

Comment: @johannchopin done, thank you for response

Comment: @DanilMednikov Nice! Now you can continue to make your question even better by adding a minimal working example (so that we just go on an url and can see the code and manipulate it to see the changes). For that you can use the incredible and helpful tool [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).